# Adding reordering to Listview

Tags: android

The Android sdk has an example Notepad app that holds notes in a database. One thing I noticed was missing was reordering items, is there a simple way that this could be added? How would the ordering be set in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that `ListView` doesn't reorder the underlying data. Instead the data presents itself in the correct order. So if you're using SQLite using a `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` would be the way to go. When you add something refresh the underlying data to refresh your list.